# libcloud: missing 1 required positional argument error during driver init

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, libcloud

I'm using:

- libcloud 2.2.1
- python 3.5.2
- virtualenv
- GCE service account with a json credential file

Python code looks like this:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver


def run():
    """ Run this script
    """
    ComputeEngine = get_driver(Provider.GCE)
    driver = ComputeEngine(user_id='****@****.com',
                           credential_file='serviceaccount.json',
                           project='****')

run()
```

When I run my code, I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 47, in <module>
    run()
  File "./myscript.py", line 21, in run
    project='ebs-it', secure=True)
  File "/***/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 1795, in __init__
    super(GCENodeDriver, self).__init__(user_id, key, **kwargs)
  File "/***/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 975, in __init__
    self.connection = self.connectionCls(*args, **conn_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'secure'
```

This looks [perfectly textbook](http://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compute/drivers/gce.html) to me. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was two fold: unfamiliarity with Google's service accounts, which led to an error in coding.

1. Each service account has an email/ID associated with it, which I only discovered after clicking on 'Manage service accounts' on the Credentials screen. I was mistakenly using my google account as the user_id, since I couldn't figure out what else to put in the field (even though that didn't make sense, but I couldn't see an alternative).
2. After examining the libcloud code, I discovered the `credential_file` parameter, which seemed to fit better than the `key` parameter that should be used for the service account file. That is what led to the actual error I was seeing.